# 1 recipient found but 0 pushes sent Push Notifications in Parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have tried sending push notifications via the Parse Framework from my iPad to my iPhone and it seems to be successful because the callback in the iOS log returns succeeded and in the push console on Parse.com it says 'You sent this push notification to 1 recipient' on the view notification page.

[image]

But I am not receiving any notifications on my iPhone and it says on the list of notifications on Parse.com: '0 pushes sent'.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: The only time i have encountered this was when i was using bookmarked urls that lead to differing versions of my parse app.. took me a while to realize and i sheepishly had a stern word with myself about it ;) ..

Comment: any information about this?

Comment: Check your provisioning profiles and other certificates are able to test push notifications on mobile devices